# calculation of general government debt from reserve bank of India's annual report

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp, government-debt, fiscal-policy, public-debt

As per Reserve Bank of India's report,

> The general government deficit and debt moderated to 9.4 per cent and 86.5 per cent of GDP, respectively, in 2022-23 (BE) from the peak levels of 13.1 per cent and 89.4 per cent in 2020-21, respectively (Appendix Table 7).

Below is the Appendix table 7:
[Appendix Table 7](https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/AnnualReportPublications.aspx?Id=1392)

How were they able to calculate the general government debt from this data?

I am sharing Reserve bank of India's annual report link as well. [RBI Annual Report](https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/AnnualReportPublications.aspx?year=2023)

I have been struggling to figure this out for days now.

Thanks in advance!